# show "detailed type" instead of "type" as default in nemo

Tags: files, configuration, mime-types, nemo, file-types

I would like to differ between SVG, JPEG, PNG images in a folder. It is anoying to always change it, so I want to set "detailed type" instead of "type" as default.

[image]

Answer (score 0):

- Nemo > Edit > Preferences > List Columns

[image]